# Managing internal Purchase Order forms/requests in CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress

I did a quick search, but only found the reverse about allowing registrations to accept incoming PO numbers.  We are looking to implement Purchase Order Forms internally, and wondering if anyone else has done so?  Cases seems like a pretty logical place to do this, but I'd love to hear about other potential possibilities.  Or if it's a terrible idea, give me some why's.  Shouldn't matter, but this is a WordPress install.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this a long time ago but it was very specific to the org's workflow. It involved a custom activity type, some autoupdating of a pdf template, and then an internal approval -> email -> offline vendor signature -> email/fax -> inbound civi email processor.

I'm not sure if cases would add anything unless there's more going on too.

You've said wordpress but possibly drupal webform plus this [online signatures](https://civicrm.org/blog/mattwire/electronic-signing-with-drupal-webform-and-civicrm) addon could be useful, i.e. the PO is a webform, and then it gets signed online by the vendor and stored in civi.

Comment: Utilizing Activities alone is an interesting idea to keep it simple.  However, Cases can allow more roles, deeper automation, and templates of checklists of multiple activities that each have their own automated follow-up reminders.  This raises the KISS conundrum.

Comment: maybe if you can spell out the likely workflow in the original question. my initial thought was Activities could deliver without the added layers of Cases.  But i tend to work with Drupal too and therefore combinations of Views and Webforms add a lot of capabilities to such workflows